# How do I add choices to google datastore StringListProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

Okay here is the problem. I have this code

```
list_categories = [None,"mathematics","engineering","science","other"]
class Books(db.Model)
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = db.StringProperty()
    isbn = db.StringProperty()
    categories = db.StringListProperty(default=None, choices = set(list_categories))
```

what i want to do here is have my book.categories be a SUBSET of list categories, for example
i have a book whose categories should be 'engineering' and 'mathematics', but when I set

```
book.categories = ['engineering','mathematics']
```

it webapp2 gives me an error

```
BadValueError: Property categories is ['engineering','mathematics']; must be one of set([None,"mathematics","engineering","science","other"])
```

My initial guess here is that i must set my list_choices to be a POWERSET of [None,"mathematics","engineering","science","other"], but this is too inefficient.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error (as I'm sure you've guessed) is that `StringListProperty` does not do any special handling of the `choices` keyword argument - it simply passes it along to the `ListProperty` constructor, which in turn passes it to the `Property` constructor, where it is evaluated:

```
if self.empty(value):
    if self.required:
        raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
    else:
      if self.choices:
        match = False
        for choice in self.choices:
          if choice == value:
            match = True
        if not match:
          raise BadValueError('Property %s is %r; must be one of %r' %
                              (self.name, value, self.choices))
```

The issue is that it iterates through each `choice` individually, but it is comparing it to your entire list (`value`), which will never result in a match since a string won't equal a list (again, you know this :) ).

My suggestion would be to modify how you assign the list to the property. For instance, instead of:

```
book.categories = ['engineering','mathematics']
```

Try something like this:

```
for category in ['engineering','mathematics']:
    book.categories.append(category)
```

Since the `ListProperty` contains a list, you can append each item individually so that it passes the test in the aforementioned code. Note that in order to get this to work in my tests, I had to set up the model in a slightly different way - however if you can get to the error you mentioned above, then the `append` method should work fine.

It makes it a little less straightforward, I agree, but it should circumvent the issue above and hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a many to many relationship using list of keys. Use the `categories` property in `class Book` as a list of keys of `class Category`.

```
class Book(db.Model)
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = db.StringProperty()
    isbn = db.StringProperty()

    # List Of Keys
    categories = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Category(db.Model)
    name = db.StringProperty(choices = ('science', 'engineering', 'math'))
```

For more info and code samples about modeling check out: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling